# Applying regular expression for content inside braces outside html

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to delete content in between `( )` by using the below reg expression in PHP and my code is deleting content inside HTML tags too. How can I over come that?

Input - An explanation(poem) is a set of `<a href="/wiki/Statement_(logic)" title="Statement (logic)">statements</a>` usually constructed to

Expected Output- An explanation is a set of `<a href="/wiki/Statement_(logic)" title="Statement (logic)">statements</a>` usually constructed to

Output I got- An explanation is a set of `<a href="/wiki/Statement_" title="Statement ">statements</a>` usually constructed to

My code is - `preg_replace('/\(([^()]*+|(?R))*\)\s*/', ' ', $string);`

Comment: Provide your code. Specifically your input, the output you got and desired output.

Comment: stop breaking the edits!!

Comment: Hi Robert, I modified my question.

Comment: What exactly isn't your preg_replace() doing that you wish it would?  It looks like it is removing the bracketed substring.  Please clarify what is wrong.  Is there a larger string that your `<a>` tags are nested inside?  We should be seeing this in your post.  Are we only looking for `<a>` tags or are there other html tags to disqualify as well?

Comment: As I am converting everything into a string, it removes all the substrings between (). I want to restrict it removing only from the text, not from <a> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method assumes you are only looking to disqualify `<a>` tags from the parenthetical substring removal process.

Pattern: `~<a.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| *\([^()]*\) *~`
Replace: 
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1wLjI/1)

If your `$string` can contain any/all html tags, you will have to loosen up the pattern a bit.

Pattern: `~<(\S+).*?</\1>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| *\([^()]*\) *~`
Replace: 
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1wLjI/2)

*Notice in my patterns that I am matching  (a literal space) instead of `\s` this is to preserve an new lines and maintain the strings intended structure.

`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` works to disqualify unwanted matched in advance.